# Accesing Lazy<T> Collection in a multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, dictionary, locking

I have `Lazy<FeedRepository>` instance that has inside a complex dictionary.

```
public class FeedRepository
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, SymbolData>> _feed = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, SymbolData>>();//SymbolData simple object 
    }

 public static class FeedContainer
    {
        private static Lazy<FeedRepository> feedRepository = new Lazy<FeedRepository>();
    }
```

The dictionary `_feed` has around 10 keys that always updates. with massive data. streamed data.

I have around 20 different clients that access this collection in runtime, I need to serialize it (the `_feed` singleton) and send it back to them.

Every tome I serialize the Dictionary I get an exception about the fact that im serializing while they are changing which is expected.

I know I can `lock` while serializing the _feed variable and this will solve the issue. but the problem is that the streaming data will be paused most of the time and won't be updated.

Im looking to a way to continue getting the data while serializing.

What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: If this is just for the purposes of display at a snapshot of time, then would a shallow copy be enough to serialize? A dirty read in that scenario could be acceptable depending on your circumstances

Comment: Use `ConcurentDictionary`. `Lazy<T>` instance is thread safe, but `T` is not.

Comment: @Sinatr - isn't ConcurentDictionary uses lock ?

Comment: I've no idea how is it implemented, but it's thread safe and not blocking (there is [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.100).aspx)), so probably it doesn't use `lock`. Read [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/when-to-use-a-thread-safe-collection#concurrentdictionary-vs-dictionary) or look into [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,2e5ef5704344a309).

Comment: Are you using a Database? If so this is better done in a stored procedure in the database than in c# code.